# MySQL - Load Infile allowing duplicate primary key entries

Tags: mysql

Best way to illustrate my problem is with a quick example.

Imagine the following file (loaded into MySQL using "Load Data Infile in Table" command)

```
Color,Shape
red,square
blue,triangle
green,circle
```

(Note: My primary key = Color. Unique Key = Shape)

No matter how many times I use the command I still (correctly) just have 3 records, as it doesn't allow duplicate records.

However, if I amend record 3 within MySQL and change it from circle to diamond and re-run the Load Data command I end up with 4 records.

```
Color,Shape
red,square
blue,triangle
green,diamond
green,circle
```

I now have 2 x green values in my Primary Key field. If I try to edit one of them I get a "Duplicate Entry for Primary Key Field" error.

I would have expected the `Load Data Infile` command to skip the record as it creates a duplicate value in the Primary Key field. Instead it seems to only ignore it if the entire record is a duplicate. It doesn't seem to validate fields to ensure that the Primary Key field is always unique.

Why is it failing to do this?

Comment: A primary key uniquely identifies a record. If one were to have duplicate primary keys, it would defeat the point.

Comment: Pete, do you know the definition of primary key and what its job is?

Comment: From the manual: "*With LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE, data-interpretation and duplicate-key errors become warnings and the operation continues because the server has no way to stop transmission of the file in the middle of the operation*". Did you use the `local` option?

Comment: @HD1..... That is the problem. I would have expected MySQL NOT to have allowed a duplicate primary key to have been created. That is the whole point of having a primary key. It should be a unique value, but the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE does not appear to observe this.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name..... yes. The LOCAL option is included mate.